# how do i delete the numbering between the sentences in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, numbering

[image: article sample]

Hi, how do i delete the numbering between the sentences. i search everywhere, and still did not find the answer. Im working with large document here.so deleting one by one is not an option. thank u.

Comment: `Paragraph Style > Bullets & Numbering`

Comment: Already answered [on the Adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1893836).

Answer (score 2):

You have extra numbers because you have extra returns. Your style gives each paragraph a number, and InDesign doesn't care if your paragraph has content or not.

You have to search/replace two returns to one return, and then if you want physical space between paragraphs, edit your style to contain Space Before.